# Recursive sum function for a linked list in java

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list, sum

I want to sum up all the values of a linked list recursively but it doesn't work. It says:

> Cannot invoke "Element.sum()" because the return value of "Element.getNext()" is null

```java
public class Element{
    private int value;
    private Element next;
}

public class MyList{
    private Element elements;
    public int sum(){
        if (elements == null) return 0;
            return elements.getValue() + elements.getNext().sum();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is unclear about "Element.getNext() is null"?

Comment: it doesnt work when the list contains 1 element.

Comment: Say you are on the last element then `element.getNext()` is null and you are trying to call `sum()`  on that null hence your error, add a null check to `getNext()` even before you call any other functions on it.

Comment: "it doesnt work when the list contains 1 element" - yes because the code is trying to get the next element which doesn't exist (it's null).  What is the question?

Comment: but there is a if clause that should return if the next is null

Comment: While `elements` (which should be `element` by the way) is checked for null, `elements.getNext()` may also be null. Invoking `sum()` on `null` throws a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```java
public class MyList{

    private Element elements;
    
    class Element{
        private int value;
        private Element next;
        Element(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
        public Element getNext() {
            return next;
        }
        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }
        public void setNext(Element next) {
            this.next = next;
        }
        public int sum() {
            if (next == null) {
                return value;
            } else {            
                return value + next.sum();
            }
        }
    }

    public MyList(int data[]) {
        Element prev = null;
        for (int value : data) {
            Element e = new Element(value);
            if (prev == null) {
                elements = e;
            } else {
                prev.setNext(e);
            }
            prev = e;
        }
    }
    
    public int sum() {
        return elements == null ? 0 : elements.sum();
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyList list = new MyList(new int[]{ 1, 2, 3});
        System.out.printf("sum = %d\n", list.sum());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As it seems you are trying to learn about recursivity, and it seems you are really trying, I won't give you a complete solution here.

First I think you didn't provide the complete code, because as is it does not compile. You are calling `elements.getNext().sum()` meaning you have a sum() method on your class Element.

And this is actually one possible correct way, to have a sum method in you Element class, because you want recursivity to happen on every Element.

So as you started this way, you should continue to try this way: add a sum method on your Element class. And this is where you can do recursivity. Recursivity meaning to call again the same method either on another instance or with another parameter...

The other answer works, but will you learn about recursivity just by copying it ? I would suggest trying to do similar thing, but in the Element class, so you manage to do it by yourself

Comment: you are right iam trying to learn recursion. The class element does contain a sum method and getters. I didnt mention it because i didnt know that when i use getnext() on element, which is from Mylist, that it returns a instance of class element and that the sum() function from class element is called instead of Mylist. Am i right ?

Comment: Yes this is correct, the method getNext() returns an Element, so getNext().sum() is calling the sum method on the Element returned by getNext()

Comment: thank you for your response. Iam slowly understanding :)

Comment: That's why I didn't give a solution like others. Better to have a question and answer discussion so you understand step by step, instead of giving a full solution :) They didn't even take the time to explain, that's not so helpful when we learn I guess...

Comment: i agree throwing solution at others wont help them understand fully

Answer (score 1):

`sum` isn't even a method of `Element`, so the implementation shouldn't compile.

I'd pass the root element to an internal `sum` method which can be recursive, and keep the no-arg `sum` method public:

```java
public class MyList {
    private Element elements;

    public int sum() {
        return sum(elements);
    }

    private int sum(Element e) {
        if (e == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return e.getValue() + sum(e.getNext());
    }
}
```

Comment: `== 0` should be `== null` - typo I guess.

Comment: @kaya3 momentary lapse of concentration, thanks for noticing! Edited and fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyList myList = new MyList();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            myList.add(i);

        System.out.println(myList.sum());   // 55
    }
}

final class MyList {

    private Element head;

    public void add(int value) {
        if (head == null)
            head = new Element(value);
        else {
            Element element = head;

            while (element.next != null)
                element = element.next;

            element.next = new Element(value);
        }
    }

    public int sum() {
        return head == null ? 0 : head.sum();
    }

    private static final class Element {

        private final int value;
        private Element next;

        public Element(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public int sum() {
            return value + (next == null ? 0 : next.sum());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused about the returning value when the list reaches zero size or empty. I assume the returning value at that instance shall be zero, which replaces the cumulative result of the summation, but still the returned value is the same!?

any elaboration is highly appreciated.

please note the code below, formed in Kotlin language.

```
fun main()
{
    val aList = listOf<Int>(1, 2, 3, 4)
    val sumResult = sumListContents(aList)
    println(sumResult)
}

fun sumListContents(intNums: List<Int>): Int
{
    return if (intNums.isNullOrEmpty())
    {
        println("--------------$intNums-------------")
        0
    }
    else
    {
        println("${intNums[0]} $intNums sub list: ${intNums.subList(1, intNums.size)}")
        return intNums[0] + sumListContents(intNums.subList(1, intNums.size))
    }
}
```